# how do i show the products that are uploaded by the logged in user only?

Tags: python, django, listview, authentication, django-views

Here's my problem, when a user logs in they can see the products uploaded by the other user also but i am trying to show when an user logged in they can see the products uploaded by them only**

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import ProductForm
from .models import Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

**prodcut create or upload**

```
def product_create_view(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ProductForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

**product update**

```
def product_update_view(request, id=id):
obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

**tried by changing in the list view but getting this error product_list_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'**

```
def product_list_view(request, user):

    queryset = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user) 

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
        }
    return render(request, "products/product_list.html", context)
```

**product detail **

```
def product_detail_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    context = {
        "object": obj
    }

    return render(request, "products/product_detail.html", context)
```

**product delete**

```
def product_delete_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        return redirect('../../')
    context = {
        "object": obj
    }

    return render(request, "products/product_delete.html", context)
```

**this is product list template page**
**template/product.list.html**

```
  {% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}

  {% block content %}

      {% for instance in object_list %}
          <p>{{ instance.id }} - <a href='{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ instance.title }}</a></p>
       {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

**here's the **
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class Product(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120) 
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:product-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id}) #f"/products/{self.id}/"
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_list_view, name='product-list'),
    path('create/', product_create_view, name='product-create'),
    path('<int:id>/', product_detail_view, name='product-detail'),
    path('update/<int:id>/', product_update_view, name='product-update'),
    path('<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='product-delete'),
]
```

Comment: Indentations are important for python code. Could you edit your question to correct that?

Comment: Please remove the boldface (boldface should be used to stress *parts* of the question). Furthermore please indent your code.

Comment: thanks for suggesting my fault ,in future i will take care of it

Comment: @redwanabir: not to worry. These are some hints to ask better questions :) such that next time, you receive a better answer in less time :).

Answer (score 1):

You never set the logged in user in your `Product` when you create or update it:

```
def product_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
    form = ProductForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', context)
```

```
def product_update_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=obj)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', context)
```

In your `product_detail_view` and `product_delete_view`, you should filter on the user as well:

```
def product_detail_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, user=request.user)
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_detail.html", context)

def product_delete_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        return redirect('../../')
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_delete.html', context)
```

in your list view, you should not use `user` as a parameter:

```
def product_list_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'object_list': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_list.html', context)
```

**Additional remarks**:

1. usually in case of a *successful* POST request, you should make a redirect, in order to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get pattern* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get);
2. you might want to make the `user` column *non-NULLable*, since now it will have NULL if you do not specify a value, and you allow to construct products without a user;
3. please do not use `request.POST or None`. A POST request can be valid, even if it is empty;
4. please do not write urls yourself, Django's [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) can resolve a URL based on the name of a view, and the values for the parameters. This is more safe if you later want to rewrite the URLs; and
5. you might want to take a look at class-based views like [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), and [**`DeleteView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView). These will reduce the amount of boilerplate logic.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! and i will always keep in mind what you have suggested.